# Fixing multiple definition error when using third party library (OpenGA)

Tags: c++

I'm fairly new to c++, and I'm using this project as a learning experience. I'm working in Visual Studio 2019, and I'm using this library

https://github.com/Arash-codedev/openGA

to try to solve a version of the vehicle routing problem.

I've run into a problem when refactoring my code into separate classes once it got unwieldy including everything in a single cpp file, although a single file was the approach outlined in the OpenGA library's examples.

Currently the bare bones structure that seems to be causing the problem is as follows.

```
Algorithm.cpp

#include "Crossover.h"
#include "EvaluateSolution.h"
...
```

```
Crossover.h

#include "GeneticStructs.h
...
```

```
EvaluateSolution.h

#include GeneticStructs.h

...
```

```
GeneticStructs.h

#include openga.hpp

...
```

The external library has the following definition:

```
openga.hpp

...
std::mutex mtx_rand;
...
```

GeneticStructs just has Chromosome and Gene structs with overloaded ostream operators for each.

The problem is when I compile, I get the following linker errors:

> Crossover.obj : error LNK2005: "class std::mutex EA::mtx_rand" (?mtx_rand@EA@@3Vmutex@std@@A) already defined in Algorithm.obj
>
> EvaluateSolution.obj : error LNK2005: "class std::mutex EA::mtx_rand" (?mtx_rand@EA@@3Vmutex@std@@A) already defined in Algorithm.obj
>
> GeneticStructs.obj : error LNK2005: "class std::mutex EA::mtx_rand" (?mtx_rand@EA@@3Vmutex@std@@A) already defined in Algorithm.obj

So from what I understand, I'm violating the one definition rule. I think I understand why. The mutex gets defined separately in each object file and results in ambiguity when the linker tries to combine the object files. Of course, exposition on what is actually wrong would be welcome, since I'm a newbie to c++.

What would be the proper way to resolve something like this? I think the context should be clear from the outline I've given, but if more is necessary please let me know! Thank you.

Comment: If the library includes a variable definition in it's header then it's broken. All you can do is avoid including that header file in more than one cpp file. Your understanding is clearly better than the author of the library.

Comment: Or you could modify the header to say `extern std::mutex mtx_rand;` and then add `std::mutex mtx_rand;` to one of your cpp files.

Comment: It seems that I'm using the library in an unanticipated manner.  Ah well. I'm going to go with the latter suggestion.Thank for the feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not your fault; it looks like a bug in that OpenGA library.

---

The normal way would be to declare the variable in the header as:

```
extern std::mutex mtx_rand;
```

Then have one (and only one) source file (e.g. `OpenGA.cpp`) in which it's defined, taking the namespace into account:

```
#include "OpenGA.hpp"
NS_EA_BEGIN
std::mutex mtx_rand;
NS_EA_END
```

Of course, this is not needed if the header is included in one (and only one) source file, which is presumably the way the library's author has been using it.

---

Since the mutex is only used to protect the `std::mt19937_64 rng` inside the `Genetic` template, it might also work to just move the mutex declaration into that template as well. I haven't checked if that would break anything, though.

Comment: Thanks!  I thought this might be the right idea but I didn't want to go modifying the library without being certain of what I was doing. Moving the declaration into the template seems to fix the problem without obvious issues, but I think I will make the declaration extern and write a source file to go with it as you suggest to be safe.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for using openGA.

This issue has been currently fixed. Please include the openGA in this way:

source1.cpp

```
#include "openGA.hpp"
...
```

source2.cpp

```
#define OPENGA_EXTERN_LOCAL_VARS
#include "openGA.hpp"
...
```

source3.cpp

```
#define OPENGA_EXTERN_LOCAL_VARS
#include "openGA.hpp"
...
```

Except for only one source file, at the beginning of all other source files that use openGA, define macro `OPENGA_EXTERN_LOCAL_VARS`. Then, you should not get such a linker error.

---

The mechanism of fix works as follows

```
#ifdef OPENGA_EXTERN_LOCAL_VARS
extern std::mutex mtx_rand;
#else
std::mutex mtx_rand;
#endif
```